# Magento 2.3.3 elasticsearch high CPU

Tags: magento2.3.3, elasticsearch

This question is already on Elasticsearch forums: [Elastic Forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-6-8-5-high-cpu-load/210641)

I am new to Elasticsearch. I use one installation on my server with version 6.8.5 for a Magento 2 instance I have. I am using java-8-openjdk openjdk version "1.8.0_222". Although it, not the first time I use the same setup now in my last scenario I have the high load in CPUs with was not there before. In peak, it goes up to 4.00 with htop saying JAVA 400% CPU.

[image: HTOP]

**jvm options:**

> -Xms15g
>
> -Xmx15g
>
> -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
>
> -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
>
> -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
>
> -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60
>
> -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10
>
> -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
>
> -Xss1m
>
> -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> -Djna.nosys=true
>
> -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
>
> -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true
>
> -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true
>
> -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0
>
> -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false
>
> -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true
>
> -Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}
>
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>
> -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch
>
> -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log 8:-XX:+PrintGCDetails 8:-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
>
> 8:-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution 8:-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
>
> 8:-Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log 8:-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
>
> 8:-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32 8:-XX:GCLogFileSize=64m
>
> 9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
>
> 9-:-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT 10-:-XX:UseAVX=2

**And elasticsearch.yml:**

> indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10024

I have specified JAVA_HOME as elastic advice and I have no errors anywhere.

Maybe I should use other JDK versions?

If someone could help me, please.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We have a memory problem mainly as elasticsearch seems to eat all the memory with same kind of processes as you have in your screenshot.

Comment: Try to remove the redirect to search for 404 errors....Also what module you use?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can just restart Elasticsearch with following command

sudo service elacticsearch restart

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I tried changing ES_HEAP_SIZE in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` and in `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch`, but when I ran ps aux | grep elasticsearch the output still showed:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g # aka 2G min and max ram
```

**This Is second option if first not work then try this one.**

I had to make these changes in:

```
/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms1g 
-Xmx1g 
# the settings shipped with ES 5 were: -Xms2g
# the settings shipped with ES 5 were: -Xmx2g
```